# Any additional considerations when using Faye in a Node.js cluster?

Tags: faye

We're planning to run an Express-based server on Node.js in "cluster mode" using Node.js' cluster support.  So there will be 1 master process and 'n' (where 'n' is calculated based on the number of CPUs) child processes running on a single machine. We already have a testbed set up using Faye for pubsub in non-cluster mode and it works great.

Are there any additional considerations we need to be aware of when using Faye on top of a Node cluster?  For example, since there will be 'n' HTTP server instances, will it be a problem creating a Faye NodeAdapter in each Node process and attaching it to the HTTP server instance in that process?

Thanks.

-brian

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the answer to my question is fairly obvious. One thing to be aware of is that Faye will need to access shared state across multiple server instances (processes). In a single-server config, you could probably get away with using Faye's memory engine.  In a clustered config, you'd need to use Faye's redis engine or some other engine that allows state to be shared by different processes. I'd prefer not to introduce another persistence component just for this purpose so I may look into implementing my own on top of my current persistent store (Neo4j).